# Проблема с ArrayAdapter spiner

Tags: android, массивы, kotlin, android-spinner

Написал такой код:

```
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
```

//Блок кода//

```
val values : Array<String> = arrayOf("USD", "UAH", "GBD", "EUR", "BIT", "RUB")
val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values)
```

Однако  IDE выдаёт ошибку

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

<init>(Context, Int, Array<(out) TypeVariable(T)!>)
  where T = TypeVariable(T) for 
  constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: Array<(out) T!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
<init>(Context, Int, Int)
  where T = TypeVariable(T) for 
  constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, textViewResourceId: Int) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
<init>(Context, Int, (Mutable)List<TypeVariable(T)!>)
  where T = TypeVariable(T) for 
  constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: (Mutable)List<T!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter Alt+Shift+Enter Alt+Enter
```

Можете подсказать в чём тут дело.

Comment: `this` у вас кто?

Comment: Функция `onCreate()` класса `HomeFragment`

Comment: Тут у человека [была](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325639/how-to-use-an-arrayadapter-in-a-fragment-with-kotlin) похожая проблема, ему посоветовали this заменить на getActivity() но тоже не сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас `HomeFragment` является `this`, то вам необходимо это заменить на `requireActivity()` или `requireContext()`.

`Fragment` в отличии от активити не наследуется от класса `Context`, а значит не может быть передан в аргументы в качестве контекста. Приведенные выше 2 метода как раз дают возможность получить контекст внутри любого `Fragment-а`